# Is there a definitive way to tell if an action causes a movement or shift in a supply-demand graph?

Tags: macroeconomics

I am taking AP Macroeconomics, and am about 2/3 of the way through the curriculum. We have learned about various supply-demand graphs, and right now we are working on the market for money. I have noticed that with every model we learn about, there are a set of rules to remember which tell whether something will be a shift in the supply-demand graph. However, it is not ideal to have to remember these rules for every model we have looked at.

Is there any general rule for what events will definitely cause a movement, and what events will definitely cause a shift?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The supply and demand curves are plotted as functions of price. Hence:

- Changes in price will result in movements.
- Changes in anything else will result in shifts.

Comment: Well what about a scenario where the Fed starts buying T-Bills from banks, giving them more available cash, which lowers interest rates. Is that not a change in price? Or is that not 'direct' enough?

Comment: @Addison: That can be modeled as the market for money, with the supply curve shifting right. We then have a downward movement along the demand curve so that indeed the interest rate falls.

Comment: I see, so it would shift supply and move demand. What is the best way to figure out if Demand or Supply shifts or moves? Or is there no 'best' way?

Comment: Any change in anything other than price will result in a shift in either or both the supply and demand curves. There is no 'best' way to figure out which of the two (or both) shifts -- it depends on the context. For example, on a sunny day, the demand for ice cream may rise (with supply unchanged), while the supply of solar-generated electricity may rise (with demand unchanged).

Comment: @Kenny LJ: Your explanations are really great and Addison, your questions are also. One question: In your first comment,  I understand that supply curve would shift right. ( because there's more money ). Why would the demand for money go down and why does the interest rate fall. Probably not good questions but I'm a total beginner with this material. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds: The demand for money does not shift. Only the supply of money shifts rightwards, this corresponds to a downright movement along the demand curve.

Comment: @Kenny LJ: okay. thanks. I will print out and read everything more carefully.

Comment: @kenny Li: I'm sorry to bother you so much I've been reading a text and the text claims that the aggregate demand function is $M_t  + V_t = P_t + y_t$ where $y_t$ is log of real output, $V_t$ is velocity of money and $M_t$ is money supply. I'm not sure if the actual good is money ( like it is in the case of this question ) but, by their definition, wouldn't an increase in money supply, shift the demand curve to the right, based on the definition ? Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds: No. If there is an exogenous increase in the money supply, there would be a movement downwards along the money demand curve. The money demand curve would not shift.

Comment: @Kenny LJ: Thanks but earlier you said that only price movements cause movements along the curves and anything else causes shifts. Is that different in this case because the actual good is the money supply itself ? thanks.

Comment: @Kenny LJ: My confusion might be what is on the horizontal axis and vertical axis when the actual good being dealt with is the money supply itself ? Am I correct in saying that, for this particular discussion, the money supply is the good ? if not, what is the good in this case ? Thanks again.

Comment: @markleeds: The good is money. The supply and demand curves are money supply and money demand. The "price" (on the vertical axis) is the interest rate.

Comment: @Kenny LJ: That's useful.I didn't know the vertical axis was interest rate. So, since the money supply itself is the good, then when the money supply is increased, it is not exogenous in that the value on the horizontal axis is increasing so it's not a shift but rather a movement. is that right ? Also, when they refer to AGGREGATE supply curve, they use total output on the x axis and price level ( of the economy ) on the y but, for any other  demand-supply curve scenario, what is on the x axis and y axis, depends on the particular example ? Thx for  patience and knowledge. No more questions.

Comment: @markleeds: Could I suggest that you post separate questions? The comments here are probably not meant or suitable for asking and answering questions.

Comment: @Kenny LJ: sure. no problem. I'll try to come up with something but need to think about what to ask so that it's clear. Thanks for help.